# Laravel subfolder routing error

Tags: php, laravel, routes, subdirectory

everyone. Need a bit of help here.

I'm setting up a Laravel project(5.2), inside Laravel's `/public` folder i have created a `/public/blog`.

If i access `example.com/blog/`  - it works fine and returns the blog's home page.

But if i click any article inside the blog, the url is `example.com/blog/article_name/` -- This gives an error. It's 404 page/route not found error from Laravel.

Any help would be great, Thank you.

Comment: @recovery thank you, tried. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Route Parameter` helps you.

Sometimes you will need to capture segments of the URI within your route. For example, you may need to capture a user's ID from the URL. You may do so by defining route parameters:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

In the same way you can use article name.

Comment: Thank you Mayank. It's a solution of course, but the blog gets updates quite often, it will be troublesome, to add/delete routes every time. I was looking for some solution in htaccess that would would soft of ignore /blog(which it does) and everything after that

Comment: I think if you have to work for crud you should use resource controller with resource route.

Answer (score 0):

you want to define the route in /routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/blog/{name}');
```